# Get Sqlite table _id instead of adapter position in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-adapterview

I copied and pasted this code from another tutorial and am adapting it for my own needs. I'd looking to put in the SQLite id of the table instead of passing over the Adapter Position. I have searched but as I'm pretty new to this it's confusing me whatever I try.

Thanks for any help.

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
static   List<DatabaseModel> dbList;
static  Context context;
RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<DatabaseModel> dbList ){
    this.dbList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
    this.context = context;
    this.dbList = dbList;

}
```

@Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

```
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.item_row, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Integer _id1= dbList.get(position).get_id();

    holder.address_h.setText(dbList.get(position).getAddress());
    holder.name_h.setText(dbList.get(position).getName());
    holder.date_h.setText(dbList.get(position).getSpare1()); // getDatetimedue needed
    holder.balance_h.setText("£" + dbList.get(position).getBalance());

    holder.address_h.setSelected(holder.address_h.isSelected());
    holder.balance_h.setSelected(holder.balance_h.isSelected());
    holder.name_h.setSelected(holder.name_h.isSelected());
    holder.date_h.setSelected(holder.date_h.isSelected());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dbList.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView address_h, balance_h, name_h, date_h;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        address_h = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvname);
        balance_h = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvphone);
        name_h = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvname_h);
        date_h = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvdate_h);


        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailsActivity.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();


        extras.putInt("position",getAdapterPosition());
        intent.putExtras(extras);

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter

Comment: AFAIK _id is already being used.

Comment: Integer _id1= dbList.get(position).get_id(); was me trying to solve the problem myself. This line of code can be removed.

Comment: I fixed this myself:    '@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition_id=getAdapterPosition();
            int position_id=dbList.get(adapterPosition_id).get_id();

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putInt("position", position_id);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailsActivity.class);

            intent.putExtras(extras);

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }'